# Angular 8 ngx-translate load translation JSON file from URL

Tags: json, angular, ngx-translate

I have a problem with ngx-translate. I'm making a component where I would like to pass an URL with JSON file with translations. For now, all translations are gathered from `/assets/i18n/` directory. My goal is to not place any translations to this folder, but to provide my component with `@Input` decorator and to pass URL to this input with the whole translation file.

This is what I managed to achieve right now:
In my `app.module.ts` file I have this function:

```
export function HttpLoaderFactory(http: HttpClient) {
  return new TranslateHttpLoader(http, 'http://127.0.0.1:8080/', '.json');
}
```

and this is working fine. I have passed my test URL as second parameter to `TranslateHttpLoader` function. But in my case, I don't want to hardcode this second parameter in my `app.module.ts`. I need to pass URL for this parameter. In case I remove this parameter from this function, my translations are not working at all. I have tried with passing this through a service, but everytime I receive an `undefined` property for this URL.

In my main component I'm setting this in constructor:

```
translate.getTranslation('http://127.0.0.1:8080/en.json');
```

Can anyone help with setting this? I could not find any solution for that.